# SetWindowsHookEx mouse callback only works 6 times

Tags: c++

i have the following

```
HHOOK g_hDesktopHook;
if((g_hDesktopHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, OnMouseEvent, NULL, 0)) == NULL)
    {
        int err = GetLastError();
        TRACE("SetWindowsHookEx failed err=%d\n", err);
    }

LRESULT CALLBACK OnMouseEvent(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    TRACE("OnMouseEvent enter\n");

    // Doesn't concern us
    if(nCode < 0)
        return CallNextHookEx(g_hDesktopHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);

    if(nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        //TRACE("OnMouseEvent HC_ACTION\n");
        if(wParam == WM_MBUTTONDOWN) {
            TRACE("OnMouseEvent WM_MBUTTONDOWN\n");
        }
    }    

    return CallNextHookEx(g_hDesktopHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The callback is not in a dll, it isn't necessary for mouse i believe. Anyhow, it work perfect 6 times, then nothing. It doesn't even enter the callback. I tried left mouse too, same problem.

Any ideas anyone?

thanks

Comment: Is that really all the code you have inside the hook, just the `TRACE`?  If you do a lot of processing inside the hook it's possible for it to timeout, the next hook will be called, and your hook will be removed with no way for you to know that happened.

Comment: that seems to be it. i had a BEEP(500,500) in there which waits for completion. i take that out and fine, thanks.